# Error with Checkbox and Duplicate Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have designed a code that creates a new worksheet based on a checkbox, and the name is derived from a User Defined Variable. However, if someone unchecks and checks the box, it runs the code again and generates an error due to multiple worksheets having the same name. I understand that this is just the code functioning as it is supposed to, but I want to create an IF:THEN statement where the code checks to see if the name exists. If the sheet exists, the code will do stop itself; if the sheet does not exist, it will run as normal.

How can I do this?

Code below.

```
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Protocol As Range

If CheckBox4.Value = True Then

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I")
Set Protocol = Sheets("The Hidden Works").Columns("W:AQ").EntireColumn
Protocol.Copy
ws.Paste
ws.Protect
ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("44").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 3).Value = "='Control'!I16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 3).NumberFormat = "General"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 4).Value = "='Control'!K16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 5).Value = "='Control'!L16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 6).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$H$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 7).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$J$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 8).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$N$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 9).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$P$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 10).Value = "=SUM(F44:I44)/D44"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 11).Value = "=M44/F3"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 12).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$U$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 13).Value = "=M44/$K$57"

Worksheets("Control").Activate

End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to check if a Sheet exists:

```
Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sheetName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Use it like,

```
If WorksheetExists("Sheet10") Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Your Code
End If
```

Your code adapted to use the solution:

```
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Protocol As Range
Dim sheetName As String

If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
    sheetName = Sheets("Control").Cells(16, "I")
    If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = sheetName
        Set Protocol = Sheets("The Hidden Works").Columns("W:AQ").EntireColumn
        Protocol.Copy
        ws.Paste
        ws.Protect
        ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Rows("44").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 3).Value = "='Control'!I16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 3).NumberFormat = "General"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 4).Value = "='Control'!K16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 5).Value = "='Control'!L16"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 6).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$H$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 7).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$J$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 8).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$N$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 9).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$P$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 10).Value = "=SUM(F44:I44)/D44"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 11).Value = "=M44/F3"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 12).Value = "=" & ws.Name & "!$U$69"
        Worksheets("SUMMARY").Cells(44, 13).Value = "=M44/$K$57"

        Worksheets("Control").Activate
    End If
End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sheetName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Comment: I like this idea, but how can I use your example of

If WorksheetExists("Sheet10") Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Your Code
End If

to look for the user defined name?

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate if a cell exists on the specifically named sheet to check:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If IsError(Evaluate("SHEETNAME!A1")) Then Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "SHEETNAME"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm rather inexperienced with VBA. Could you please explain how this code works?

Comment: @TomStone Where you generate the sheet would be replaced, i.e., Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)), by the 3 lines of code I have input.  You would specify the name of the sheet being created as it is being added (a little efficiency).  The intent of this code is to check if there's an error when trying to access cell A1 in the sheet you would otherwise create.  If it causes an error (meaning the sheet doesn't exist, can't find it), then the sheet is created; if there isn't an error, then it doesn't do anything and moves onto the next line.  Alerts disabled during the check.

Comment: @TomStone This only stops the new sheet from being created, then the rest of the code would execute as intended.